# Using ViewPager with include layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I don't know if this is a bug or if I'm just not supposed to do things this way but I am trying to include a viewpager twice on a page and the second viewpager never shows up.

ActivityMain.java

```
//These are my two includes in activity_main
View includeOne = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_include_primary);
View includeTwo = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_include_secondary);

//Set viewpager one
ViewPager pagerOne = (ViewPager) includeOne.findViewById(R.id.pager_viewpager);
CustomAdapter adapterOne = new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
pagerOne.setAdapter(adapterOne);

//set viewpager two
ViewPager pagerTwo = (ViewPager) includeTwo.findViewById(R.id.pager_viewpager);
CustomAdapter adapterTwo = new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
pagerTwo.setAdapter(adapterTwo);
```

activity_main.xml

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_include_primary"
    layout="@layout/pager"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_include_secondary"
    layout="@layout/pager"/>
```

pager.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter  {

    public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                return FragmentOne.newInstance();
            default:
                return FragmentTwo.newInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

The two fragments are standard.

I've been trying this all day and just can't get the second viewpager to show unless I ditch the include (which I don't want to do). Any other android view I used works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 2 viewpagers on display you need to have 2 different viewpagers and set them one above the other.

In activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.viewpager_test.app.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_include_primary"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/pager_one"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_include_secondary"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/activity_main_include_primary"
        layout="@layout/pager_two"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

For pager_one.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager_viewpager_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For pager_two.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager_viewpager_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and in your ActivityMain.java file set your pagerOne to be viewpager_one id and pagerTwo to be viewpager_two id:

```
ViewPager pagerOne = (ViewPager) includeOne.findViewById(R.id.pager_viewpager_one);
...

ViewPager pagerTwo = (ViewPager) includeTwo.findViewById(R.id.pager_viewpager_two);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer :)
Fair enough, but that kinda defies the point in having an include file. Ie misc changes to the pager file would have to be made in two files, not one.